# finding regular exprssions from a list of string examples

Tags: python, regex, string

Is it possible to find regular expressions given matching examples?

```
examples = [
     "my name is Alice",
     "my name is Alex",
     "my good name is Bruce"
]
```

I need to find a possible regular expression programmatically which matches all the above examples. For the given example set above, python regex would be `my (.*)name is (.*)` or `my (\w)name is (\w)`.

EDIT: I need to write a script which automates the extraction of regex for me.

Comment: try something like `my\\s?.*?\\s?name is (.*?)`

Comment: No, the question is how do i write a script which automatically extracts the regular expression when i present it with matching examples ?.  You took a look at the examples and wrote a regex. I want a program to do that

Comment: Do you need to find the regex programmatically, meaning you want a piece of software to give your the matching regex? If that is so, maybe do `(my name is Alice)|(my name is Alex)|(my good name is Bruce)`. That will be easy to string together with code.

Comment: That will fail if i try to match `my name is John`

Comment: `my name is John` is not in your examples. How should a piece of code know what portion of the sentence is the one that is allowed to vary?

Comment: `.*` will match all of them

Comment: It can know that, because it is presented with multiple examples. I can easily do this when the example set contains `my name is connor kelly`, `my name is alex`, `my name is bruce`. My script would generate regex `my name is (.*)` which would match `my name is john` as well. Since, in above example, `my good name is bruce` has an extra word `good` in between, i somehow need to render all the examples into having same length (length=no.of words here).

Comment: What you have in mind is impossible

Comment: @ShivaprasadBhat [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3141762/1192111)'s a possible solution to your problem (it's in ruby, so you'll have to translate it to Python)

Comment: @hek2mgl It is not impossible. One answer is provided by Francisco Couzo

Comment: Did you *read*, *understood* and implemented that? Meaning did you solved your problem or not?

Comment: Yes. I implemented it the same day i asked the question. I just uploaded the minimalistic version of the regex-utils i have been working on to github. https://github.com/shivylp/RegexUtils

Comment: P.S. I did not refer the link posted by Francisco Couzo. So i don't know the approach used there. I found my own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented a solution myself. I made a small python package out of it and put it in my Github repo @ http://github.com/shivylp/RegexUtils

If anyone is looking for something similar, can use it.

Answer (score 0):

If it is just that, try:

```
regex = '(' + ')|('.join(examples) + ')'
```

Comment: It's not that bad. It's doing what the OP requested. Generate a regex that matches all of his examples.