# Regex crossword solver

Tags: regex, string, algorithm, performance, time-complexity

Following [Find string to regular expression programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46211505/find-string-to-regular-expression-programmatically), we assume that it takes linear time to find a string that matches a regex. My intiution says that we can solve a regex crossword programmatically too, right?

If yes, what will be the time complexity of solving a NxM regex crossword?

Example:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's NP hard, even if you disallow backreferences. There's a simple mapping from the [exact set cover problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_cover) to this problem.

If you have sets `S[1], S[2], ..., S[n]` (with union `S`), and without loss of generality, the sets contain all the numbers 1...N for some N. Represent the `S[i]` as a string of length N, with `1` in the k'th place if k is in `S[i]`, and `0` otherwise.
Let the columns of your regexp puzzle be all the same -- `0*10*`, and the k'th row be "(S[k])|(0*)".

For example, if `S[1] = {1, 4}, S[2] = {2}, S[3] = {3}`, and `S[4] = {2, 3}`, then the puzzle would be:

```
         0*10*  0*10*  0*10*  0*10*
1001|0*
0100|0*
0010|0*
0110|0*
```

A solution to this regexp puzzle is an exact cover of {1, 2, 3, 4} with the `S[i]`.

Comment: "even if you disallow backreferences." What do you mean?

Comment: Your example in the question has `\1` and `\2` which are not part of regular expressions, although some implementations allow them. In general, determining if a regexp with backreferences matches a string requires exponential time.